# query optimization for max function in oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, query-performance

I am having a table name x which contain week-no where datatype of week number is varchar2 which fetches max(week-no) in 22 second.
I need to fetch row with max week-no
I tried this below query:

```
select max(to_number(week-no))
from x;
```

please help and suggest the query which can take less time.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a functional index:

```
create index x_weekno_num on x(to_number(week_no));
```

I think Oracle should be smart enough to use the index for your query.  If not, you can try:

```
select week_no_num
from (select to_number(week_no) as week_no_num
      from x
      order by to_number(week_no) desc
     ) x
where rownum = 1;
```

I should also point out that if you are storing the number as a character string, then you should pad it with zeros (so "01", "02" and so on).  In that case, you can just use `max(week_no)` and an index directly on the column.